# Use of "es" in "Ich kann es kaum erwarten"

Tags: modal-verb

I told a friend about a TV show we both watch and because I'm learning German and he's German himself, he replied:

> Ich kann es kaum erwarten.

Looking this up on a dictionary, I worked out that **kaum erwarten können** is roughly the English equivalent to *"to can hardly wait"*

But, the use of es slightly confused me.

I translated his sentence as

> I can hardly wait.

but the es was what stuck me.

Do we use es in the following sense:

> I can hardly wait (for it)

i.e. an object that können needs?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's a mandatory accusative object the verb *erwarten* needs. The thing you *await*.

> Ich erwarte einen Anruf.

*I await a call.*

> Ich kann deinen Anruf kaum erwarten.
>
> Ich kann ihn kaum erwarten.
>
> Ich kann es kaum erwarten, dass du anrufst.